# Ubuntu 18.10 problem with Nvidia 340 drivers

Tags: nvidia, drive

I have a Nvidia 210 graphic card but, after installing the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10, Nvidia 340 drivers were installed and my system got stuck at the Ubuntu logo screen. I went into the recovery mode and removed them and now everything is fine.  So, what is the issue, and how can I fix it? Or, is there an alternative to using those drivers?

Comment: The issue has been fixed in later releases of ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

NVIDIA make script is using cc link for compiling nvidia.ko. check cc link with command: `sudo update-alternatives --list cc` and if necessary replace cc target with command: `sudo update-alternatives --config cc`.

NVIDIA driver and Linux kernel must be compiled with the same gcc version.

install NVIDIA kernel driver with command: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340` or manually run NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.107.run script as root user.

after installation generate proper xorg.conf file with command: `sudo nvidia-xconfig`. normally nvidia-xconfig set proper value of DPI for your monitor.

to adopt proper DPI setting for your monitor specify your desired DPI by placing desired value inside section "Monitor" of your /etc/X11/xorg.conf. for example: Option "DPI" "96 x 96"

logout an login to apply new settings for the X server.